# Append div dynamically to li if the class is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the ul li format for my menu

```
<li class="dropdown active list-unstyled clearfix">
       <a target="_self" href="/marine-offshore/en/worldwide/sustainability/"><span>Sustainability</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown active list-unstyled clearfix">
       <a target="_self" href="/marine-offshore/en/worldwide/sustainability/"><span>Sustainability</span></a>

    </li>
```

In the above code in First LI have `div class="dropdown-menu"`. But for the second `LI` i dont have the `div class="dropdown-menu"` to append that `div` I have used below code but its getting appending to both the `li`.

```
if( !$('.mainnavigation li.dropdown').hasClass('dropdown-menu') ) {
       $('.mainnavigation .dropdown').append("<div class='dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><div class='nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs'></div></div>");
}
```

Please help me out to append the `div` only to the second `li` alone. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the second element in the jQuery way.

```
if( !$('.mainnavigation li.dropdown').eq(1).hasClass('dropdown-menu') ) {
       $('.mainnavigation .dropdown').eq(1).append("<div class='dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><div class='nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs'></div></div>");
}
```

Comment: Is that eq value can be dynamic instead of specifying as 1 or 2

Comment: Sure, just use a variable for the number. :)
Like `var myIndex = 3`, then use `.eq(myIndex)`Then you

Comment: Then you can calculate myIndex on the fly. Like so:
`myIndex = $('.mainnavigation li.dropdown').length - 1;`

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript test, you are testing if the LI element has the class "dropdown-menu".

You can test the presence of the div you want with this code :

```
 $('.mainnavigation li.dropdown').each(function(){
   if($(this).children('.dropdown-menu').length == 0){
$(this).append("<div class='dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><div class='nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs'></div></div>");
}
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gxnnwy3r/

Answer (score 0):

You can access direct second element like:

USE eq() function.

```
$('.mainnavigation .dropdown').eq(1).append("<div class='dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><div class='nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs'></div></div>");
```

Comment: But in future the number of LI can be added. we have to check whether the class is there or not and then we have to append.

Comment: also check condition by using eq function

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
if($('.mainnavigation li.dropdown .dropdown-menu').length === 0 ) {
     $('.mainnavigation .dropdown').append("<div class='dropdown-menu second-nav-subList fivecol-nav col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><div class='nav-promotions col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 hidden-xs'></div></div>");
}
```

it will check if `.mainnavigation li.dropdown` has any element like `.dropdown-menu` and if `length` is `0` that *(means there is no element)* only then add it in .